# Chromium takes too long to load! (1+ minute)

Tags: lubuntu, chromium

From Lubunu 19.10, chromium installed via Snap, takes more than 1 minute to load!
On 19.04 it loaded quickly.
On 19.10 the CPU and disk activity is passive.
Since Lubuntu isn't based on gnome, is it still the gnome keyring that causes this issue?
Starting from command terminal, I get the following message:

```
2019/11/02 07:49:47.909894 cmd_run.go:893: WARNING: cannot start document portal: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Documents': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)
[3019:3019:1102/074957.830615:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(369)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[3019:3019:1102/074959.900320:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)]     [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
[3019:3019:1102/075000.217065:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
[3273:1:1102/075003.454035:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(81)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[3273:1:1102/075003.461309:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(81)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[2738:3268:1102/075012.008643:ERROR:udev_watcher.cc(94)] Failed to begin udev enumeration.
```

Closing the browser gets me this:

```
[3300:1:1102/075130.946231:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(81)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[3300:1:1102/075130.948724:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(81)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[3300:1:1102/075130.957598:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(81)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[3300:1:1102/075130.960825:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(81)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[3529:1:1102/075518.059456:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(81)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[3529:1:1102/075518.063894:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(81)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[3019:3019:1102/080045.664588:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
[3019:3019:1102/080240.782721:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
```

Comment: I stopped using GNOME when Gnome switched from 2 to 3, but still use many GTK+ applications. Those programs will naturally use GTK+ libraries and tools (such as gnome-keyring) as it's expected by the *]application]* coders, which has nothing to do with my choosing & using LXQt on my Lubuntu.  Chromium does not come with Lubuntu; you've added it to your system, so it'll use whatever tools/toolkits/features the [*application*] developers decided to use for it.  Snaps starting slower though is a different issue.

Comment: IIRC, gnome keyring affects those who choose to auto-login.

Comment: It seems to work fine on any other pc. Just my laptop has an issue. I since moved over to FireFox, and don't have the issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is a flag

`--disable-gpu` which may help since it is a compositor issue on a headless chrome